# grouping and then verify two conditions with characters variables R

Tags: r, dplyr, character, subset

I would like to understand how to verify two conditions in groups with R. Like if I have:

```
x <- data.frame("id" = c('A12', 'A12', 'A13', 'A13', 'A14', 'A14'), 
                "var1" = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), 
                "var2" = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'y', 'x'), 
                "var3" = c('h', 'l', 'l', 'h', 'q', 'q),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

for the group with the ID A12 are 'a', 'x' and 'h' present in the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', we may need to wrap with `any` if the whole group have at least one row with the condition satisfied

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(flag = any(var1 == 'a' & var2 == 'x' & var3 == 'h'))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   id [3]
#  id    var1  var2  var3  flag 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>
#1 A12   a     x     h     TRUE 
#2 A12   b     y     l     TRUE 
#3 A13   b     z     l     FALSE
#4 A13   c     z     h     FALSE
#5 A14   b     y     q     FALSE
#6 A14   a     x     q     FALSE
```

---

Or another option is to `paste` the columns, and then do a string match

```
library(stringr)
 x %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(flag = any(str_c(var1, var2, var3) == 'axh'))
```

If it is just to create a column of TRUE/FALSE, then remove the `any` and the `group_by` step

Comment: Thanks, akrun. What if I want to check two conditions across a group, even in the same column, and then count how many time the condition is respected?

Comment: @allerkonge You can remove the `any` and wrap with `sum`